# golang can not print inner string

Tags: go, sdk

I want to usego sdk on a c++ project. But i am in a problem, the problem is mainly like this. I am running a go program using a c function, the code can be simplified to below.

package main

```
 // #include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                        
 // #include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                       
 /*                                                                                                                                                           
 void print() {                                                                                                                                               
     printf("just for test");                                                                                                                                     
 }                                                                                                                                                            
 */                                                                                                                                                           
 import "C"                                                                                                                                                   

 func main() {                                                                                                                                                
     C.print()                                                                                                                                                
 }
```

But the result is none, there is no output. Who can tell what's the problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Don't spam tags. C is a completely unrelated language.

Comment: I get it -_-, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C stdio is buffered, so it doesn't produce output right away.  In a C program, exiting main or doing exit() runs atexit handlers, one of which installed by the runtime will flush the stdout buffer.  You likely need to do:

```
void print() {
    printf("just for test");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Or flush stdout somewhere else if you don't want to do it every time for speed reasons.

Comment: so exit in golang will not flush the stdio buffer?

Comment: Fairly certain that's true.